# MS Unit Test -- Can I include DB Unit test / Coded UI test in single Test Project Solution?

Tags: asp.net

Can I include DB Unit test / Coded UI test in single Test Project Solution?

That Means, Same unit test project has:

-- DB Test Methods
-- Coded UI test mthods
-- Code Test methods

Answer (score 0):

Ok so to answer your question directly..... yes you can.

Some of the tests you're describing, particularly DB tests, are integration tests. These are tests that rely on external dependencies to your code (like a database). These are perfectly valid tests but shouldn't be referred to as Unit Tests.

There are some high level definitions of test types here:
[Types of Software Testing](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/types-of-software-testing/)

Comment: What is the benefit to separating the tests into different projects? TFS and Visual Studio have built in mechanisms for categorizing, organizing, and running different sets of tests.